# PHP - Efficiency while searching for palindrome

Tags: php, performance

I was challenged by a friend to code some PHP to find the longest palindrome in provided text, my solution is below, how could I make it more efficient?

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://challenge.greplin.com/static/gettysburg.txt");

echo $string;

function isPalendrone($string) {
  if ($string == strrev($string))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

$longest = "";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string)-1; $i++) {
  $afterCurrent = substr($string, $i);
  for($j = 0; $j < strlen($afterCurrent)-1; $j++) {
    $section = substr($afterCurrent, 0, $j);
    if(isPalendrone($section)) {
      if(strlen($longest)<strlen($section)) {
        $longest = $section;
      }
    }
  }

}

echo "<br /><br/>The longest was: ".$longest."<br /> which is ".strlen($longest)." chars long";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reverses the entire string and just does `substr()` matches against each:

```
$rev = strrev($txt);
$len = strlen($txt);
$longest_len = 0;
$longest_str = null;

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i)
{
  for ($j = $len - $i; $j > $longest_len; --$j)
  {
    if (substr($txt, $i, $j) == substr($rev, $len-$i-$j, $j))
    {
      $longest_len = $j;
      $longest_str = substr($txt, $i, $j);
      break;
    }  
  }
}
```

I didn't try to optimize the implementation. e.g., It might be a little faster to skip the `substr` and do a char-by-char approach, because you could break out faster. In that case, you wouldn't really even need to reverse the string.

Answer (score -1):

To get the **longest** palindrome - you have to start with longest string (not with shortest like you do now), check it and break on first match.

Also you'd better just keep 2 pointers (`$i` and `$j`) and not perform `substr` twice. It is enough to have i and j and `substr` once, right before you perform `if(isPalendrone())` condition.

My implementation (~20% faster than yours):

```
<?php

$string = 'FourscoreandsevenyearsagoourfaathersbroughtforthonthiscontainentanewnationconceivedinzLibertyanddedicatedtothepropositionthatallmenarecreatedequalNowweareengagedinagreahtcivilwartestingwhetherthatnaptionoranynartionsoconceivedandsodedicatedcanlongendureWeareqmetonagreatbattlefiemldoftzhatwarWehavecometodedicpateaportionofthatfieldasafinalrestingplaceforthosewhoheregavetheirlivesthatthatnationmightliveItisaltogetherfangandproperthatweshoulddothisButinalargersensewecannotdedicatewecannotconsecratewecannothallowthisgroundThebravelmenlivinganddeadwhostruggledherehaveconsecrateditfaraboveourpoorponwertoaddordetractTgheworldadswfilllittlenotlenorlongrememberwhatwesayherebutitcanneverforgetwhattheydidhereItisforusthelivingrathertobededicatedheretotheulnfinishedworkwhichtheywhofoughtherehavethusfarsonoblyadvancedItisratherforustobeherededicatedtothegreattdafskremainingbeforeusthatfromthesehonoreddeadwetakeincreaseddevotiontothatcauseforwhichtheygavethelastpfullmeasureofdevotionthatweherehighlyresolvethatthesedeadshallnothavediedinvainthatthisnationunsderGodshallhaveanewbirthoffreedomandthatgovernmentofthepeoplebythepeopleforthepeopleshallnotperishfromtheearth';

function isPalendrone($string) {
  return $string == strrev($string);
}

$longest = '';
$length = strlen($string);

for ($i = 0; $i < $length - 1; $i++) {
    for ($j = $length - $i; $j > 1; $j--) {
        if (isPalendrone(substr($string, $i, $j))) {
            $new = substr($string, $i, $j);
            if (strlen($new) > strlen($longest)) $longest = $new;
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo "<br /><br/>The longest was: ".$longest."<br /> which is ".strlen($longest)." chars long";
```

Comment: This won't work with short string like 'bb'.